# All values get added in HashMap, but only the last values get returned

Tags: java, hashmap, jakarta-mail, return-value

In the below method **demoReadEmail2(String folderName)**, I am getting only last element of the `HashMap`. However on debug and during print all value are getting properly.

```
public Map<String, Object> demoReadEmail2(String folderName) throws MessagingException,IOException {
    Map<String, Object> stringObjectHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Message message : getUnseenMailsByCurrentDate(folderName)) {
        stringObjectHashMap.put("From",message.getFrom()[0]);
        stringObjectHashMap.put("To",Arrays.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)));
        stringObjectHashMap.put("CC",Arrays.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)));
        stringObjectHashMap.put("BCC",Arrays.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)));
        stringObjectHashMap.put("Subject",message.getSubject());
        System.out.println(stringObjectHashMap);
    }
   return stringObjectHashMap;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how many `Message` objects `getUnseenMailsByCurrentDate(folderName)` returns... You're using the same set of keys, and a map supports only one entry per key. So only the last `Message` will reflect in the map. Maybe you want to return a `List<Map<String, Object>>` instead.

Comment: To help you think about this problem, think about what keys and values you *want* to be in the resulting Map. If you're imagining more than one `"From"` key, then what you are imagining is not how a Map works, so you need to go back and specify the problem differently. I suggest returning a `List<Message>` should be enough work for one method, and then converting one `Message` into a `Map<String, Object>` should be enough work for another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the HashMap properties every time your loop is executed. A way of achieving what you want would be to have a `Collection`, like a `List`, this way:

```java
public List<Map<String, Object>> demoReadEmail2(String folderName) throws MessagingException,IOException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Message message : getUnseenMailsByCurrentDate(folderName)) {
        Map<String, Object> stringObjectHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        stringObjectHashMap.put("From",message.getFrom()[0]);
        stringObjectHashMap.put("To",Arrays.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)));
        stringObjectHashMap.put("CC",Arrays.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)));
        stringObjectHashMap.put("BCC",Arrays.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)));
        stringObjectHashMap.put("Subject",message.getSubject());
        myList.add(stringObjectHashMap);
    }
   return myList;
}
```

Comment: Do not put HashMaps into a HashSet! The hashCode of a HashMap object depends on its contents, but its contents are mutable. You should only put things into a HashSet if their hashCode cannot change later. Better use a `List<Map<String,Object>>` if you want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You're filling the map in the loop, crushing the value associated with the same keys at each iteration. See [Put Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-)

You may have at best... one entry in the map for each key (`"From"`, `"To"`,...).

If you need to keep track of several values associated with the same key, you may use a `Map<String, List<Object>>` instead: refer to this [Key Collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653140/java-hashmap-how-to-handle-key-collision-for-grid-of-words/) topic.
Another alternative is `List<Map<String, Object>>` or add index info to your entries keys: e.g. `From1`, ... (by using the index in the loop).

Answer (score 0):

A map maps a key to a single value:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
map.put("key1", "value1");   // Puts value1 in map
map.put("key1", "value2");   // Overwrites value1
```

So it depends upon what you are trying to do.

If you want a list of all "From", create separate lists for each part:

```
List<String> froms = new ArrayList();
froms.add(fromValue);
```

If you want a Map with multiple values, use a Multimap.

Google "java tutorials collections" for a nice tutorial.